# How can I make road-side tension adjustments to bladed spokes?

Tags: wheels, spokes, tools

Bladed spokes like the Sapim CX-Ray require a special tool to hold them in place while turning the nipple, to prevent them from twisting.

Say I break a spoke while on the road and need to make adjustments to neighbouring spokes to compensate. I'm unlikely to have such a spoke holder on me. Are there any clever techniques I can use here, or do I need to add a spoke holder to my repair kit?

Comment: A bladed spoke will work as a spoke even in completely the wrong position.   It will just be less aerodynamic,and possibly louder.   Do you need anything other than the nipple driver tool ?

Comment: @Criggie I've had a bladed spoke permanently deform through twisting when trying to adjust the tension, due to a stiff nipple. I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 8):

I've built wheels with bladed spokes, and never had to use any tool to prevent spoke windup like that.

Simply turn the nipple *past* the point where the tension would be correct, then turn it back to where you want it, so that the spoke isn't twisted.  You'll probably need to perform a few trial-and-error attempts to get how far past the target you'll have to go correct, but it's not hard.

And this is a roadside repair - if the spoke winds up twisted a bit, so what?  You can fix it when you get back.

FWIW, [bladed spokes aren't all the much more aerodynamic](https://novemberbicycles.com/blogs/blog/from-the-vault-spoke-aerodynamics): "... at 30mph the difference between the two wheels is 1.8 watts ..."

Comment: Later comments by Josh Poertner on his podcast make it sound like the delta is bigger. This was likely based on wind tunnel testing for teams or wheel manufacturers, but unfortunately he didn’t show data.

Comment: Bladed spokes also have the benefit of being stronger than butted spokes.

Comment: I’ve twisted several bladed spokes before I got a proper spoke holder. It’s even worse when you don’t grease the nipples.

Comment: @Michael So how do you remove or prevent windup from non-bladed spokes?  If windup is a problem, it's a problem for all spokes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I was wondering the same, I guess with round spokes you first of all don’t notice and second their shape is stronger against torsion. With bladed spokes you loose some of the aerodynamic advantage when they are twisted.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Non-bladed spokes are much more resistant to wind-up. For example, a Sapim CX-Ray spoke should twist about twice as much as a circular one of the same cross-sectional area, and about 4 times as much as a regular 1.8 mm double-butted spoke (working from the [torsion constant definitions in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_constant)).

Comment: Anyway, for 1.8 mm spokes I'd usually just turn the nipple back an eighth of a turn or so to compensate for wind-up, but if that calculation is correct and it's going to wind up by a *half turn*, something tells me that's not good for the spoke!

Comment: I'd be tempted to try filing a slot in a tyre lever, to one side near the end that doesn't contact the bead. I've made a spanner that way (I needed 11mm) in a metal tyre lever that already had a spoke notch, but this should work in a good solid plastic one. I don't have bladed spokes to test, or I'd make this an answer

Comment: @AndrewHenle Also bear in mind that after a few years of use, the nipples might not want to turn on the spoke, so that wind-up becomes a much bigger problem than when first building the wheel.

Comment: @ChrisH This is a great idea! I will try it out with a tyre lever.

Comment: @WillVousden *after a few years of use, the nipples might not want to turn on the spoke* If so, you can't adjust the spoke at all.  Either the spoke turns in the nipple or it doesn't, and if it does you can overturn it and then back it off to remove the windup.

Comment: @AndrewHenle My point is that the nipple might well turn, but only with enough force that the spoke reaches its elastic limit and deforms permanently or breaks. This has happened to me before with an old Mavic Ksyrium, so it's not just a theoretical possibility! If a spoke has already broken, the last thing I want to do is break/damage its neighbour as well while trying to adjust its tension!

Comment: @WillVousden How does that problem not also apply to non-bladed spokes?

Answer (score 4):

On longer trips I carry this IceToolz Bladed Spoke holder with me (along with a spoke wrench and spare spokes and nipples):

[image]

It has two gaps of different width. I only need the narrower one for my spokes so I’ve cut the tool in half to reduce weight and size. I can’t recall the weight of the tool but I think it’s like 10g or so.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a small crescent wrench to apply torque to the blade in the opposite direction while adjusting the nipple.

Note: I use this on steel spokes and can’t speak to how it might damage carbon spokes.

[image]

Comment: Do you suggest carrying such a tool at all times? They're not light, even the small ones

Comment: I do but I ride with a backpack. The one in the picture is about 46g. That might be an subjective issue for a road rider.

Comment: To be fair, that tiny one isn't much heavier than the stamped multi spanner I carry - but with less leverage for other stuff, and slightly harder to pack in my tool case.

Comment: @ChrisH sounds like a good excuse to buy a titanium one !